# Grails - Remote Field and Ampersand

Tags: ajax, grails

I noticed something when I was attempting to use remoteField ajax tag in grails. When I enter an ampersand (&), that value is not recognized in my controller when obtaining the parameter value.

Example: I will type Cat & Dog
What I see: Cat

How can I avoid this? Is this a known bug? I couldn't find anything online about this.

**Edit**

I'm pretty sure this is due to url encoding and parameters, since an ampersand is usually a parameter delimiter. Just not sure how to get around this.

```
<g:remoteField action="getName" update="testDiv" paramName="search" name="nameSearchResults" value="" />
```

Controller:

```
def getName() {
    println "Search result = " + params.search
    //When typing "Cat & Dog" I get:
    //Search result = C
    //Search result = Ca
    //Search result = Cat
    //Search result = Cat 
    //Search result = Cat
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried URL encoding the text in your `remoteField`?

I would recommend adding a `before` property with JavaScript to URL encode the input:

```
<g:remoteField action="getName" update="testDiv" paramName="search" name="nameSearchResults" value="" before="encodeURIComponent(this.value); return true;" />
```

You will then have to decode it in the controller.

Comment: I'm pulling the raw param.searchField value from the remoteField. It truncates the ampersand and everything after it. I need a way from the view to modify the string being passed as a param.

Comment: OK - so what I would recommend you do is urlEncode the text in your remoteField using JavaScript and then decode in your controller. To attach a JavaScript function to your remoteField, use the 'before' property. (This seems to be an issue with IE...Have you tried Chrome and/or Firefox?)